# Sorting within specified range and loop until done - VBA Excel Marcro

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

It's me again. I've been trying different alternatives to sort the rows based on Col D per collection.

This is the closest one, yet there are 2 bugs found.

1- Loop and not able to exit when it reaches the last used rows.
It keeps sorting until I press  to force quitting
2- It's unable to sort where there is only one SKUs per collection
It sort the next collection as well. Sometimes 3 collections sorted.
e.g. Before Run - Row 9, 29, 32, 35, 45....

Here is my code. What's wrong with my code?

```
Sub SortingCollectionOnColD
With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    Set FindSubtotal = .Find("Subtotal", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not FindSubtotal Is Nothing Then
            firstOne = FindSubtotal.Address
            Do
                With FindSubtotal
                        Range("A" & FindSubtotal.Row - 1).Select
                        Set SortRange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).EntireRow
                        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                            ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C" & FindSubtotal.Row) _
                                , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
                            With ActiveSheet.Sort
                                .SetRange SortRange
                                .Header = xlNo
                                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                                .Apply
                            End With
                End With
                Set FindSubtotal = .FindNext(FindSubtotal)
            Loop While Not FindSubtotal Is Nothing And FindSubtotal.Address <> firstOne
        End If
End With End Sub
```

**Before the run**

[image: Before the run]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result]

**After the run. highlighted the major failures**

[image: After the run. highlighted the major failures]

Comment: Your `With FindSubtotal`... End With` does not do anything. I tried your code, but properly declaring all variables and using the sheet instead of the A:A range, where it looks strange for  me, it works as expected (by me...). I cannot post it here, because you will not understand anything. I will try an answer instead. Please test it and let me know if it works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Please test the next code, please. I could not reproduce your sheet and I changed the reference to sheet instead of A:A range, where it looks logic to me, but not knowing very well what you wanted to do, it would not be impossible to not return what exactly you need. Please let me know if/how it fits your need.

```
Sub LoopSubtotal()
  Dim FindSubtotal As Range, sh As Worksheet, firstOne As String
  Dim SortRange As Range
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   With sh.Range("A:A")
    Set FindSubtotal = .Find("Subtotal", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not FindSubtotal Is Nothing Then
            firstOne = FindSubtotal.Address
            Do
                sh.Range("A" & FindSubtotal.row - 1).Select
                Set SortRange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).EntireRow
                sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    sh.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("C" & FindSubtotal.row) _
                        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
                    With sh.Sort
                        .SetRange SortRange
                        .Header = xlNo
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .Apply
                    End With
                    Set FindSubtotal = .FindNext(FindSubtotal): Debug.Print FindSubtotal.Address
            Loop While Not FindSubtotal Is Nothing And FindSubtotal.Address <> firstOne
        End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Try, please, running it line by line, pressing F8 and see what it does.

Comment: It keeps sorting and doesn't stop when it sorted last used row. Similar result as my code.